# What is the difference between BulkProcessor and BulkRequestBuilder - elasticSearch (java)?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I worked with `BulkRequestBuilder` and it works fine, but I also want to use the `BulkProcessor`. Can anyone help me understand what is the difference between them?

Comment: `BulkRequestBuilder` is good to do a one-off bulk request at various points in time. `BulkProcessor` has a higher-lever interface and provides good optimizations if you need to do more frequent bulk operations.

Comment: The `BulkRequestBuilder` let's you submit several requests in one go where you control when it happens. The `BulkProcessor` collects a predefined number of requests and sends them to the server in one go when the number is reached or a certain time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

The `BulkRequestBuilder` is part of the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk.html#java-docs-bulk) and allows one to index and delete several documents in a single request.

And, according to the documentation section [Using Bulk Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk-processor.html):

> The BulkProcessor class offers a simple interface to flush bulk operations automatically based on the number or size of requests, or after a given period.